# 3d navigation and collision detection

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I am new to Open GL. I am trying to navigate through a tubular structure, which was developed using Open GL primitives.I have done almost that. But now my problem is to stop the camera when it is hitting on the tube boundaries. Can anybody give suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcomes to SO , please follow [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),it will be easy to get your solutions

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL is not a scene graph or a game engine. It just draws points, lines or triangles, one at a time, as pixels to a framebuffer. That's it.

Anything that goes beyond that you have to implement yourself. You want collision detection? OpenGL won't do it for you.¹ You want a scene? You'll have to implement the data structures for that yourself.

In the case of a camera in a tube the boundary condition is simple: If the camera's distance from the tube centerline (most easily expressed in cylindrical coordinates) approaches the tube radius, stop the movement in that direction.

---

¹ Not entirely true: You can use OpenGL to implement things like collision detection, but this is not straightforward and usually less efficient than doing it with special purpose collision detection code.

Comment: I want something like 3d collision detection. The created tube is having different radius and have some bends too. So it is not possible to create a boundary detection as you said. I want to set the camera inside the tube and it should not go beyond the boundary.